# Exporting basemap & Layers as an image?

Tags: openstreetmap, open-source-gis, export, image

I need a open-source server-side component for a web-application that can export basemaps + layers to an image format (saved on a db).
Being slightly new to GIS, I've managed to find a few tools that do this on the client-side.

- leaflet's plugin Leaflet.print does this. I'm using leaflet to display CloudMade tiles on the browser.  it has npm packages, so I'm guessing it can run server-side as well.
- OpenLayers 3 (beta) has this as an example but I've not tested it out.
- MapFish Print
- GeoServer which uses MapFish Print again.

Is there any component that could take in map bounds & a features as geoJson and output image file on the server-side ?
It would not be possible to use ArcGIS or proprietary tools

Comment: What is the problem/limitations of your current picked components?

Comment: Hi Sid, have you managed to do this?